# Retrieving Data Faster Using Django from a Large Database

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I have a large database table of more than a million records and django is taking really long time to retrieve the data. When I had less records the data was retrieved fast.

I am using the get() method to retrieve the data from the database. I did try the filter() method but when I did that then it gave me entire table rather than filtering on the given condition.

Currently I retrieve the data using the code shown below:

```py
context['variables'] = variable.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

I know why it is slow, because its trying to go through all the records and get the records whose id matched. But I was wondering if there was a way I could restrict the search to last 100 records or if there is something I am not doing correctly with the filter() function. Any help would be appretiated.

Comment: What kind of database are you using? A `.get` on ID should give you relatively fast lookups since the primary key is usually indexed.

Comment: I am using Microsoft sql server 2017 Enterprise as my Database.

Comment: Hm, that should be ok then. Try executing raw SQL and see if you get the same performance issues. If so, it might take some EXPLAIN work to see where the query's bogging down: `variable.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM VARIABLE where id = %s', [self.kwargs['pk']])` You'll need to tweak that line to get it to work I imagine.

Comment: Is the id/pk column indexed in the database?